# CodeIgniter static class question

Tags: php, codeigniter, static, singleton

If I would like to have several static methods in my models so I can say `User::get_registered_users()` and have it do something like

```
public static function get_registered_users()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `is_registered` = 0";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    // etc...
}
```

Is it possible to access the `$this->db` object or create a new one for a static method?

Comment: Many of the frameworks don't use static methods for various reasons. The foremost of which is late static binding which is offered in PHP5.3 but not before. You will be unable to use `$this` in a static method, you'll have to instantiate a new db instance and call query on that.

Comment: @Matt: Correct, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

`get_instance()->db...`

or

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->db->get('users')->result();
$CI->session->set_userdata('login', TRUE);
```

Comment: Would be helpful, when posting a suggestion to the OP source code, to actually use the OP source code and change that.

Answer (score 0):

Matt S is correct, though Kohana was built for PHP5, so previous compatibility isn't much of an issue.

Static methods do not have access to other variables. If the variable was defined as self::db you could use it then, and you might want to instantiate it that way to do it.

Static methods are best for things that don't require objects, such as formatting text, redirecting pages, etc.